# scrapy dosn't stop after yield in python

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to make a spider that goes through a certain amount of start urls and if the resulting page is the right one I yield another request. The problem is that if I try anyway of not yielding a second request the spider will stop directly. There are no problems if I yield the second request.

Here is the relevant code:

def start_requests(self):
urls = ['https://www.hltv.org' + player for player in self.hashPlayers]
print(len(urls))
for url in urls:
return [scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)]

```
def parse(self, response):
    result = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'playerTeam']//a/@href").get()
    if result is None:
        result = response.xpath("//span[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' profile-player-stat-value bold ')]//a/@href").get()

    if result is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = "https://www.hltv.org" + result,
            callback = self.parseTeam
        )
```

So I want a way to make the spider to continue after I call the parse function and don't yield a request.

Comment: Didn't you just made this same question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983118/scrapy-stops-directly-after-i-dont-yield-a-request-in-parse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy stops directly after I don't yield a request in parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983118/scrapy-stops-directly-after-i-dont-yield-a-request-in-parse)